# How to get a running total in SQL without using cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem mentioned below

```
wkSales    ytdSale      
2839        15513      
2925        18202      
2705        20693      
2643        22499      
2515        24688      
1999        26128
```

I want to add wkSales of second row to ytdSales of first row and show their addition in second Row of ytdSale Column how can i achieve this in sql server 2008 please help me

Comment: You need to use [lead](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx).

Comment: Sorry abhi and all I forgot to mention that i am using sql server 2008

Comment: Sorry. Lead and Lag are available only in Sql server 2012. I will have to find something else.

Comment: You don't seem to have a column that allows us to sanely define "first", "second", etc. Do you in fact have one or more such columns (e.g. a date, perhaps)?

Comment: there are good answers...  I'm going to point to one big discussion here on SO...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance/11313533#11313533