# Dynamic Cursor Function to calculate running total

Tags: sql-server

**Background:**

I frequently need to calculate running totals for several different tables in a database.

Afer several hours of research on running total calculations (the most useful explanation for me was probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance) post on Stackoverflow which gives a brief summary of each method) I chose the cursor approach which works very well.

**Problem:**

I have to rewrite the running total cursor for each of the different tables I want to calculate running totals for and I want to know whether there are any workarounds for this? Is it possible to create a function that takes table/column names as input parameters and returns a table with the running total?

**My Attempt:**

My first step was to create a dynamic query which uses several variables (I do have checks in place to make sure the table and columns exist):

```
    SET @SQLStatement   = '
            DECLARE rt_cursor CURSOR
                FOR
             SELECT ' + @DateColumn + ', SUM(' + @ValueColumn + ')
               FROM ' + @TableName + '
           GROUP BY ' + @DateColumn + '
           ORDER BY ' + @DateColumn

   EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstatement

   OPEN rt_cursor
```

which works well...

I then tried to incorporate this into a function however (for reasons that are now very clear to me) this didn't work (EXEC IN Function Does Not Work)

...So I decided to ask for help.

**PS:** I'm a novice, newbie, what-ever-you-like-to-call-it and while I appreciate criticism, I just want to get this working as best I can. I only do this part-part-time and don't have time to learn all the ins-and-outs and dos-and-donts of proper SQL so a solution rather than a theory lesson would be appreciated - even if it is just "This Won't Work".

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to create a stored procedure instead, which will allow you to do everything you want.  The procedure would take in your variables as parameters (@DateColumn, @TableName, etc.).

You've got a couple of options for returning your results:

1. You could create a temp table before calling the procedure that the procedure fills.
2. Return the results at the end of the procedure, and upon calling, you can drop the results into a table.
3. If you already have a table to store results, just insert them at the end of your procedure

Comment: Thank you @jmk - don't know why I didn't think of that :(