# Strange TSQL behavior with COALESCE when using Order By

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by, coalesce

I'm having some very strange behavior with coalesce. When I don't specify a return amount (TOP (50)) I'm only getting a single last result, but if I remove the "Order By" it works... Examples below

```
DECLARE @result varchar(MAX)
SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ',', '') + [Title]
FROM Episodes WHERE [SeriesID] = '1480684' AND [Season] = '1' Order by [Episode] ASC
SELECT @result
```

Will only return a single last result:

> The Shiva Bowl

But If I specifiy a max return amount (only adding **TOP (50)** to same statement)

```
DECLARE @result varchar(MAX)
SELECT TOP(50) @result = COALESCE(@result + ',', '') + [Title]
FROM Episodes WHERE [SeriesID] = '1480684' AND [Season] = '1' Order by [Episode] ASC
SELECT @result
```

I get all the results in proper order

> The Draft,The Bounce Test,Sunday at Ruxin's,Mr. McGibblets,The Usual Bet,The Shiva Bowl

The culprit seems to be the [Title] column as if I return a different column it seems to be working without specifying a return limit. FYI [Title] is a VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL column.

Any insight what could be causing this? I really don't want to set a limit, but it's the only way it's returning all the data at the moment... Thanks

Comment: This is uncommented hack and you should not do like that. There are standart ways of doing this with xml.

Comment: This is the reason we go for `XML Path()` to concatenate rows into single string

Comment: [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76d79/2/0)

Comment: You can't rely that SQL Server will concatenate the first value, then the second, then the third one, and so on. It handles data on batches, so I believe that's why your case is not working. I suppose when you are using `TOP` clause and forcing ordering in such way, the engine is processing the values one by one.

Comment: @Sick I have answered the question in the past I think exactly what you want. This is a trick with exp log functions. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486877/how-to-calculate-running-multiplication/29487107#29487107

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I need to build a complex custom comma delimited string from the results, and that's why I'm not using the FOR XML output...

Comment: @bfritz, what do you mean? Can you show us that complex string?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - No here logic is quite different. I am the one who asked the question you referred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot depend on concatenation like:

```
SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ',', '') + [Title]
FROM Episodes
...
```

[Execution Plan and Results of Aggregate Concatenation Queries Depend Upon Expression Location](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287515)

Example dependent on CTE/temp table/execution plan you will get different results:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3106/0)**

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
       ,@text2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS INT) AS number 
INTO #numbers 
FROM master..spt_values 


;WITH numbers (number)
AS
(
    SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS INT) AS number
    FROM master..spt_values 
),a AS
(
    SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE number < 10
)
SELECT      @text = @text + LTRIM(STR(a.number))
FROM        a
ORDER BY    a.number DESC


;WITH numbers (number)
AS
(
    SELECT number FROM #numbers
),
a
AS
(
    SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE number < 10
)
SELECT      @text2 = @text2 + LTRIM(STR(a.number))
FROM        a
ORDER BY    a.number DESC

SELECT @text, @text2;
```

I made sample and your first query is working [SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76d79/2/0). But your solution is higly dependent on execution plan.

Use **[XML + STUFF](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)** for concatenation instead.

Comment: That SQLFiddleDemo shouldn't be working! That is exactly what I'm having this issue with, yet it's working there...

Comment: @bfritz My SQL fiddle has different structure/statistics/indexes and so on. But this is excelent example how it is dependent on internal representation and execution plan

Comment: I may just have to stick with the TOP (50) hack to force the execution, I use this same method in a few other places already, and being my service handles over 80 million requests a day I try to steer away from solutions that have lots of nested selects etc due to server load. I just need to build a string (with a single select query) and return it back FAST!