# How can I write stored procedure truncate only tables of the specific schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have different types of schema in my database. If I want to delete the tables with staging schema, how can I modify this stored procedure ?

```
CREATE PROC sp_Truncate
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?'
END
GO
```

Is there any way I can pass a parameter (type `varchar` or `nvarchar`) for the schema name ?

Comment: In general you can qualify table name with schema name, so instead of just giving the simple table name, include schema name, like "schema.table"

Comment: `sp_MSforeachtable` and `sp_MSforeachdb` are notorious for missing tables and databases. Use `sys` cataloge views as suggested in `MM93` answer.

Comment: `DELETE`, `DROP` or `TRUNCATE`: which do you really want?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 5):

It is safe to use `Delete` statement without `where` clause instead of `truncate` which may fail if you have `referential constraints`. Try this query

```
Declare @sql Nvarchar(max)=''

SELECT @sql += ' delete from ' + s.NAME + '.' + t.NAME 
              +' Go DBCC CHECKIDENT ('''+s.NAME + '''.''' + t.NAME+''', RESEED, 0) GO '
FROM   sys.tables t
       JOIN sys.schemas s
         ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE  t.type = 'U' 
and s.name = 'schema_name' -- your schema name

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Cursor Version:

```
DECLARE @s_name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @t_name VARCHAR(128) 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT  s.NAME as  Schema_Nam , t.NAME as Table_Name
FROM   sys.tables t
       JOIN sys.schemas s
         ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE  t.type = 'U' 
and s.name = 'schema_name'   

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @s_name,@t_name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       set @sql += ' delete from ' + s.NAME + '.' + t.NAME 
                  +' Go DBCC CHECKIDENT ('''+s.NAME + '''.''' + t.NAME+''', RESEED, 0) GO '   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @s_name,@t_name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Still can be wrong see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287515 code like `SELECT @Variable +=  someField
FROM    Table;` is  dependant on physical implementation and internal access paths

Comment: I would stick to `truncate` instead of delete , less logging and much faster but your sys cataloge view approach is better than the `sp_MSforeachtable` approach. Also Truncate can only be used if the table is not being referenced by any other table.

Comment: @lad2025 - Yep i know that. But to me it never failed. We can use Cursor instead

Comment: @M.Ali - That's the reason I chose `Delete`

Comment: `But to me it never failed`. Great argument really!

Comment: @lad2025 - Fix your query for `referential constraints` or alteast you can mention it

Comment: Done + demo why it may fail [SELECT @Variable += someField FROM Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806457/strange-tsql-behavior-with-coalesce-when-using-order-by/32806605#32806605)

Comment: @lad2025 - Added Cursor Version

Comment: @MM93 Great, add also that truncate reset identity column and delete not. And I don't have more question **** :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use (keep in mind that `sp_msforeachtable` is undocummented stored procedure):

```
EXEC Sp_msforeachtable 
    @command1='Truncate Table ?', @whereand='and Schema_Id=Schema_id(''SchemaName'')';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d25e32/1/1)**</kbd>

`sp_msforeachtable` parameters:

> **@command1** - is the first command to be executed by
>   "sp_MSforeachtable" and is defined as a nvarchar(2000)
>
> **@whereand** - this parameter can be used to add additional constraints
>   to help identify the rows in the sysobjects table that will be
>   selected, this parameter is also a nvarchar(2000);

*Warning:*

I assume your staging area tables don't have foreign keys. Otherwise it may fail.

## Do not name stored procedures with `sp_` prefix:

> In SQL Server, the sp_ prefix designates system stored procedures. If
>   you use that prefix for your stored procedures, the name of your
>   procedure might conflict with the name of a system stored procedure
>   that will be created in the future. If such a conflict occurs, your
>   application might break if your application refers to the procedure
>   without qualifying the reference by schema. In this situation, the
>   name will bind to the system procedure instead of to your procedure.