# Product Final Price after Many Discount given

Tags: sql, sql-server, price, discount

I have two tables.
One table of Ids and their prices, and second table of discounts per Id.
In the table of discounts an Id can has many Discounts, and I need to know the final price of an Id.

What is the Best way to query it (in one query) ?
The query should be generic for many discounts per id (not only 2 as mentioned below in the example)

For example
Table one

```
id  price   
1   2.00   
2   2.00   
3   2.00
```

Table two

```
id  Discount   
1   0.20   
1   0.30   
2   0.40   
3   0.50   
3   0.60
```

Final result:

```
id  OrigPrice   PriceAfterDiscount  
1   2.00        1.12     
2   2.00        1.20      
3   2.00        0.40
```

Comment: Are you sure Final prices you gave are correct?

Comment: yes,
for example of ID =1, the calculation is : 2 * (1-0.2) * (1*0.3) = 1.12

Comment: So the discount is held as a fraction, correct?

Comment: yes, decimal (18,2)

Comment: (1*0.3) or (1-0.3)? Do you mean those are percents?

Comment: You will need running multiplication approach which is quite complex approach. See my answer here for the ideas https://stackoverflow.com/a/29487107/1651298

Comment: 1*0.3 - will give me the amount of discount,
multiplying with (1-0.3) - will give me the price after the deduction of the discount amount

Comment: Giorgi, its not exactly the same as in your example you run with one baseline per raw. in my example - each id has its own baseline you need to multiply many times.

Comment: Take a look at this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912258/6305294

Comment: The link posted by @GiorgiNakeuri is what you need, just remove the OVER part like this: `price
            * EXP(SUM(LOG( discount )))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's another way to do it:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Price, T1.Price * EXP(SUM(LOG(1 - T2.Discount)))
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Price
```

The EXP/LOG trick is just another way to do multiplication.

If you have entries in T1 without discounts in T2, you could change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN.  You would end up with the following:

```
ID   Price   Discount
4    2.00    NULL
```

Your logic can either account for the null in the discounted price column and take the original price instead, or just add a 0 discount record for those.

Comment: Brilliant !
the easiest solution so far, and also the shortest !
thank you very much @PhillipXT

Comment: The running multiplication using EXP(SUM(LOG())) works fine for small precision of decimal expansion. When the required precision of decimal expansion is high , the above method fails.

Comment: can you give an example it will fail ?

Comment: Not sure about precision, but here's another post that has some more information about the limits of this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416169/mutiplication-aggregate-operator-in-sql

Answer (score 4):

Generally it can be done with a trick with `LOG/EXP` functions but it is complex.
Here is a basic example:

```
declare @p table(id int, price money)
declare @d table(id int, discount money)

insert into @p values
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 2)

insert into @d values
(1, 0.2),
(1, 0.3),
(2, 0.4),
(3, 0.5),
(3, 0.6)


select p.id, 
       p.price, 
       p.price * ca.discount as PriceAfterDiscount  
from @p p
cross apply (select EXP(SUM(LOG(1 - discount))) as discount FROM @d where id = p.id) ca
```

For simpler(cursor based approach) you will need a recursive `CTE`, but in this case you need some unique ordering column in `Discounts` table to run it correctly. This is shown in @Tanner`s answer.

And finally you can approach this with a regular [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql)

Comment: Nice approach, much less SQL than my answer!

Comment: Assuming there could be IDs without discount, OUTER APPLY might be better suited with `COALESCE(ca.discount,1)` in PriceAfterDiscount  calculation

Comment: @NenadZivkovic, I agree and I am leaving this for erezlale.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this produces the desired results using a CTE to iterate through the discounts. The solution below is re-runnable in isolation.

**Edited:** to include data that might not have any discounts applied in the output with a left join in the first part of the CTE.

```
CREATE TABLE #price
(
    id INT,
    price DECIMAL(5, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE #discount
(
    id INT,
    discount DECIMAL(5, 2)
);

INSERT INTO #price
(
    id,
    price
)
VALUES
(1, 2.00),
(2, 2.00),
(3, 2.00),
(4, 3.50); -- no discount on this item

INSERT INTO #discount
(
    id,
    discount
)
VALUES
(1, 0.20),
(1, 0.30),
(2, 0.40),
(3, 0.50),
(3, 0.60);

-- new temporary table to add a row number to discounts so we can iterate through them
SELECT d.id,
       d.discount,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY d.discount) rn
INTO #GroupedDiscount
FROM #discount AS d;

-- note left join in first part of cte to get prices that aren't discounted included
WITH cte
AS (SELECT p.id,
           p.price,
           CASE
               WHEN gd.discount IS NULL THEN
                   p.price
               ELSE
                   CAST(p.price * (1.0 - gd.discount) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
           END AS discountedPrice,
           gd.rn
    FROM #price AS p
        LEFT JOIN #GroupedDiscount AS gd
            ON gd.id = p.id
               AND gd.rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.id,
           cte.price,
           CAST(cte.discountedPrice * (1.0 - gd.discount) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS discountedPrice,
           cte.rn + 1 AS rn
    FROM cte
        INNER JOIN #GroupedDiscount AS gd
            ON gd.id = cte.id
               AND gd.rn = cte.rn + 1
   )
SELECT cte.id,
       cte.price,
       MIN(cte.discountedPrice) AS discountedPrice
FROM cte
GROUP BY id,
         cte.price;

DROP TABLE #price;
DROP TABLE #discount;
DROP TABLE #GroupedDiscount;
```

Results:

```
id  price   discountedPrice
1   2.00    1.12
2   2.00    1.20
3   2.00    0.40
4   3.50    3.50  -- no discount
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `EXP(SUM(LOG()))` is the way to do the calculation. Here is basically same approach from yet another angle:

```
WITH CTE_Discount AS 
(
    SELECT Id, EXP(SUM(LOG(1-Discount))) as TotalDiscount
    FROM TableTwo 
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT t1.id, CAST(Price * COALESCE(TotalDiscount,1) AS Decimal(18,2)) as FinalPRice
FROM TableOne t1
LEFT JOIN CTE_Discount d ON t1.id = d.id
```

[SQLFIddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a89aa/3)