# sql running total or Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join

I need running VoucherNo concatenation just like running balance or total.. Concatenate the previous VoucherNo to current VoucherNo row wise just like shown in picture
[image]

Query is:

```
select 
v.VoucherDate,v.VoucherNo,v.VoucherType,v.Narration,SUM(v.Debit) Debit , SUM(v.Credit) Credit,dbo.GetBalance(v.CompanyProfileId,v.AccountCode,v.VoucherDate ,SUM(v.Debit), SUM(v.Credit)) Balance
from AcVoucher v
where v.VoucherDate Between '2016-03-24' and '2016-03-30' and v.CompanyProfileId = 2 and v.AccountCode = '05010001'
group by v.VoucherNo,v.VoucherDate,v.VoucherType,v.Narration,v.CompanyProfileId,v.AccountCode
```

Schema :

```
    GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AcVoucher]    Script Date: 03/30/2016 3:47:02 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AcVoucher](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyProfileId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [VoucherNo] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [VoucherType] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [VoucherDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Narration] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Debit] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Credit] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TaxPercentage] [float] NULL,
    [DiscountPercentage] [float] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ACVoucher_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: There is no *previous* voucher number unless you have a column specifying the ordering.  And, it is not clear what that column is.

Comment: What is wrong with the query you have?   Are you getting an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate running total / running balance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using basically the same logic as for string concatenation in SQL Server.  The only difference is the `where` clause.

One key issue is the ordering for the concatenation.  This is not apparent in the question, so I added a `minid` to the query and this is used (in reverse order) for selecting the ids to bring together:

```
with v as (
      select v.VoucherDate, v.VoucherNo, v.VoucherType, v.Narration,
             SUM(v.Debit) as Debit , SUM(v.Credit) as Credit, 
             dbo.GetBalance(v.CompanyProfileId, v.AccountCode, v.VoucherDate,
                            SUM(v.Debit), SUM(v.Credit)
                           ) as Balance,
             min(id) as minid
      from AcVoucher v
      where v.VoucherDate Between '2016-03-24' and '2016-03-30' and
            v.CompanyProfileId = 2 and v.AccountCode = '05010001'
      group by v.VoucherNo, v.VoucherDate, v.VoucherType,v.Narration, v.CompanyProfileId, v.AccountCode
     )
select v.*,
       stuff((select ',' + cast(v2.VoucherNo as varchar(8000))
              from v v2
              where v2.minid >= v.minid
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as RunningConcat
from v;
```