# SQL Server 2008: Need to do math on the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Working in SQL Server 2008 so the analytical functions are not an option.

Basically I have amount financed and payment made, but need to calculate interest for the first row - which is done, but need for the next row so need to grab the balance from the previous row.

Comment: The problem is that SQL should not have any built in notion of "previous row".  SQL is set-based.  Order is something that you have to build in.  Don't be deceived by the fact that a query brings back data in a table-like structure.

Comment: Your friends are called `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER`. But without your actual table's structure and some test data you won't get much help...

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance Probably it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Here is another reference that I just used earlier today to do this https://sqlscope.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/lag-and-lead-for-sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 3):

Without any schema context, I can only provide a general structure, but in SQL Server 2008 you should be able to do something like this:

```
-- This is called a CTE (Common Table Expression)
-- Think of it as a named sub-query
;WITH computed_table AS (
    -- The ROW_NUMBER() function produces an ordered computed
    -- column ordered by the values in the column specified in
    -- the OVER clause
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS row_num
          ,*
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT *
      -- perform calculations on t1 and t2
      ,(t1.amount - t2.amount) AS CalculatedAmt -- example calcuation
FROM computed_table t1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM computed_table t2
    WHERE t2.row_num = t1.row_num - 1
) AS prev
```

The CTE and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function are necessary to make sure you have a perfectly ordered column with no gaps, something which can't be guaranteed with a primary key field since rows could be deleted. The `OUTER APPLY` allows you to perform a table-valued operation on the individual values of the rows in the left hand table.

**EDIT:** To insert the results into a table, rather than just selecting them, you can add a `INSERT` clause after the `SELECT` clause:

```
...(CTE HERE)...
SELECT *
      -- perform calculations on t1 and t2
      ,(t1.amount - t2.amount) AS CalculatedAmt -- example calcuation
-- This INSERT clause will insert the result set into my_table. Make 
-- sure the column aliases in the SELECT clause match the column names 
-- in my_table.
INTO my_table 
FROM computed_table t1
...(REST OF QUERY HERE)...
```

Comment: I like your solution and I must admit, that I changed my (much to complicated) approach to the `row_num - 1` you are using... Voted your's up for this...

Comment: It's looking good so far. Have to leave work, but will finish up adding more of the real columns tomorrow. Thanks Will vote you up regardless, as this is the direction I needed.

Comment: How would I use the insert statement on the query? I am getting the data I want, but need to insert into a table.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to insert the results instead of selecting them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, Test VARCHAR(100),SortKey INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'Test 1 3',3),(2,'Test 2 4',4),(3,'Test 3 1',1),(4,'Test 4 2',2);

WITH Sorted AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SortKey) AS Nr
          ,*
    FROM @tbl      
)
SELECT s.Test
      ,(SELECT prev.Test FROM Sorted AS prev WHERE s.Nr=prev.Nr+1) AS PreviousRow
      ,(SELECT nxt.Test  FROM Sorted AS nxt  WHERE s.Nr=nxt.Nr-1)  AS NextRow
FROM sorted AS s
```

#### Attention

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` will only work as expected, if the values you are sorting after are unique!

The result

```
Test     PreviousRow    NextRow
Test 3 1    NULL        Test 4 2
Test 4 2    Test 3 1    Test 1 3
Test 1 3    Test 4 2    Test 2 4
Test 2 4    Test 1 3    NULL
```

Comment: If the column you're sorting on doesn't contain unique values, you can add additional sort columns (e.g. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1, col2, col3,...)`) until you achieve a set of columns which will always have unique values.

Comment: @MichaelL. I know this, that's why I wrote "value **s** ". But there are tables, where you do not have uniqueness even with all columns together. In this case one could set a CTE before this CTE and calculate a `ROW_NUMBER` first and use this  as unique sort crit afterwards. This would be random in the first go, but should suffice for this purpose...