# Query for remaining amount in Report builder

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Report Builder 3.0 for Sales portal. Am Using Microsoft Dynamics Navision R2 with SQL database. I need to recall a flow field named "Remaining Amount" from the Cust. Ledger Entry Table. SQL does not have a flow field function and hence difficulty arises. Can someone guide me. There is an option of calculating again in Report Builder, but am not able to retrieve it.

Comment: What is a "flow field"?  Is it the same as a running balance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate running total / running balance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance)

Comment: It is somewhat similar to running balance where the value of the field is calculated from another table with certain criteria