# How to create a MySQL Query with accumulation on a created field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `Invoice` and `Receiving`, and I am using MySQL. I want to generate a balance sheet from these two tables. The result should accumulate a balance over time based on the `I_Total` column from `Invoice` and the `CR_Amount` column from `Receiving` as shown in the figures below. I have tried many queries with different joins but I am not getting the desired output.

[image]

How can I achieve the desired balance sheet with a query or function in MySQL?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877) should give you some ideas.

Comment: why debit transaction for 8/4/18 goes before credit one?

Comment: @IlyaBursov - that's the way a bank does it... applying all of the debits first, and then the deposits.  (My cynical nature thinks the banksters do it that way to their advantage. If my account has a starting balance of 200, and a deposit of 400 and debit of 300 on the same date, by applying transactions in that specific order, the bank can see (temporarily) a negative balance, and charge an overdraft fee. Which is why I'm a member/owner of non-profit Credit Union.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we ignore the `balance` column for a moment, and assuming that the date column is `DATE` datatype, then getting the result shown can be achieved with something like this:

```
SELECT t.date
     , t.debit
     , t.credit
  FROM ( SELECT i.i_date       AS date
              , i.i_total      AS debit
              , 0              AS credit
              , 'i'            AS i_or_r
              , i.i_id         AS id
           FROM invoice i
          UNION ALL
         SELECT r.r_date       AS date
              , 0              AS debit
              , r.r_total      AS credit
              , 'r'            AS i_or_r
              , r.r_id         AS id
           FROM receiving r
       ) t
 ORDER
    BY t.date
     , t.i_or_r
     , t.id
```

---

To get the balance, we could do that processing on the client side, as the rows are retrieved.

NOTE: MySQL 8.0 introduces  window functions, which have been available in  other RDBMS such as SQL Server and Oracle (calls them "Analytic Functions").

Without window functions, to get it done in the SQL is going to be ugly.

We could make use of unsupported usage of user-defined variables. Using this approach, we would basically emulate the processing that we would do on the client side, fetching through the result that query (processing each row in order) to add/subtract from a "running balance" in a user-defined variable.
The "ugly" part about this is that it relies on behavior that is not guaranteed. The MySQL Reference Manual includes warning about it.)

Or, to get the result using pure SQL, we could use a couple of complicated looking correlated subqueries to sum up the debit and credit amounts up to the current row, and do that for each row.

It looks like we are applying debits and credits towards the balance in a similar order that a bank does, applying all of the debits and credits in date order. And on each date, we apply the debits first, and then the credits.

From the sample data and expected result, it's not clear if debits are applied ordered by amount in ascending order, or by id in ascending order.

With the sample data, we get the same balance result either way. Assuming that `i_id` is unique in invoice, and `cr_id` is unique in receiving, we can get the balance by applying credits and debits using `id` order as a discriminator when we're at the current date.

(If we need to apply credits on the same date in ascending amount order, the subqueries would be a little more complicated, to take into account the possibility that two credits on the same date could be for the same amount.)

```
SELECT t.date
     , t.debit
     , t.credit

     , ( SELECT SUM(bi.i_total)
           FROM invoice bi
          WHERE bi.i_date <= t.date
            AND ( bi.i_date < t.date
                OR ( t.i_or_r = 'i' AND bi.i_id <= t.id )
                )
       )
     - ( SELECT SUM(br.cr_amount)
           FROM receiving br
          WHERE br.cr_date <= t.date
            AND ( br.cr_date < t.date
                OR ( t.i_or_r = 'r' AND br.cr_id <= t.id )
                OR t.i_or_r = 'i'
                )
       ) AS balance

  FROM ( SELECT i.i_date       AS date
              , i.i_total      AS debit
              , 0              AS credit
              , 'i'            AS i_or_r
              , i.i_id         AS id
           FROM invoice i
          UNION ALL
         SELECT r.cr_date      AS date
              , 0              AS debit
              , r.cr_amount    AS credit
              , 'r'            AS i_or_r
              , r.cr_id        AS id
           FROM receiving r
       ) t
 ORDER
    BY t.date
     , t.i_or_r
     , t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT *, SUM(Debit) OVER(ORDER BY dt,debit ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)-SUM(Credit) OVER(ORDER BY dt,debit ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) Balance
FROM (
SELECT ID,Dt,Amount AS Debit,0 AS Credit FROM Debit
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,Dt,0 AS Debit,Amount AS Credit FROM Credit
)X 
ORDER BY DT
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/19d7a/11)**

Comment: afair mysql does not support `sum over`

Comment: @IlyaBursov 
Actually I've tested in Mariadb. 
also I've gone through Mysql references & there is nothing like it does not support in it.

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

Kindly let me know if i'm wrong.

Comment: apparently mysql introduced window functions less than year ago

Comment: @IlyaBursov  window functions were introduced in MySQL 8.0, but are not available in previous versions. GA (General Availability) release of MySQL 8.0 was less than one month ago (2018-04-19).