# Get running balance of a work center using partition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am writing a script that will run on SQL Server 2014.

I have a table of transactions recording transfers from one work center to another. The simplified table is below:

```
DECLARE @transactionTable TABLE (wono varchar(10),transferDate date
                      ,fromWC varchar(10),toWC varchar(10),qty float)

INSERT INTO @transactionTable
SELECT '0000000123','5/10/2018','STAG','PP-B',10
UNION
SELECT '0000000123','5/11/2018','PP-B','PP-T',5
UNION
SELECT '0000000123','5/11/2018','PP-T','TEST',3
UNION
SELECT '0000000123','5/12/2018','PP-B','PP-T',5
UNION
SELECT '0000000123','5/12/2018','PP-T','TEST',5
UNION
SELECT '0000000123','5/13/2018','PP-T','TEST',2
UNION
SELECT '0000000123','5/13/2018','TEST','FGI',8
UNION
SELECT '0000000123','5/14/2018','TEST','FGI',2

SELECT *, 
    fromTotal = -SUM(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY fromWC ORDER BY wono, transferdate, fromWC),
    toTotal = SUM(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY toWC ORDER BY wono, transferdate, toWC)
FROM @transactionTable
ORDER BY wono, transferDate, fromWC
```

I want to get a running balance of the fromWC and toWC after each transaction.

Given the records above, the end result should be this:

[image]

I believe it is possible to use `SUM(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY...`, but I am not sure how to write the statement. When I try to get the increase and decrease, each line always results in 0.

How do I write the `SUM` statement to achieve the desired results?

**UPDATE**

[image]

This image shows each transaction, the resulting WC qty, and highlights the corresponding `from` and `to` work centers for each transaction.

For example, looking at the second record on 5/11, 3 were transferred from PP-T to TEST. After the transaction, there were 5 in PP-B, 2 in PP-T, and 3 in TEST.

Comment: The best solution will depend on the version of SQL Server. This is a very comprehensive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11313533/6305294

Comment: @Alex, I added the version details to the post. I am aware of your suggested prior post, and am already using the `SUM OVER` option. I believe I can get the desired results, I am just not sure how to `partition` and `order` the data to get the desired results.

Comment: Why is `TEST` fromBalance = 2 on "2018-05-11"? What are the starting balances?

Comment: Please see the updated description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get close, except starting balances:

```
SELECT  wono, transferDate, fromWC, toWC, qty,
    SUM( CASE WHEN WC = fromWC THEN RunningTotal ELSE 0 END ) AS FromQTY,
    SUM( CASE WHEN WC = toWC THEN RunningTotal ELSE 0 END ) AS ToQTY
FROM( -- b
    SELECT *, SUM(Newqty) OVER(PARTITION BY WC ORDER BY wono,transferdate, fromWC, toWC) AS RunningTotal
    FROM(-- a
            SELECT wono, transferDate, fromWC, toWC, fromWC AS WC, qty, -qty AS Newqty, 'From' AS RecType
            FROM @transactionTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT wono, transferDate, fromWC, toWC, toWC AS WC, qty, qty AS Newqty, 'To' AS RecType
            FROM @transactionTable
        ) AS a
    ) AS b
GROUP BY wono, transferDate, fromWC, toWC, qty
```

My logic assumes that all balances start at 0, therefore "STAG" balance will be -10.

How the query works:

1. "Unpivot" the input record set into "From" and "To" records with quantities negated for "From" records.
2. Calculate running totals for each "WC".
3. Combine "Unpivoted" records back into original shape

### Solution 2

```
WITH CTE
AS(
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY wono, transferDate, fromWC, toWC ) AS Sequence
FROM @transactionTable
 ),
 CTE2
 AS( 
 SELECT *,
    fromTotal = -SUM(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY fromWC ORDER BY Sequence),
    toTotal = SUM(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY toWC ORDER BY Sequence)
FROM CTE
 )
SELECT a.Sequence, b.Sequence, c.Sequence, a.wono, a.transferDate, a.fromWC, a.toWC, a.qty, a.fromTotal + ISNULL( b.toTotal, 0 ) AS FromTotal, a.toTotal + ISNULL( c.fromTotal, 0 ) AS ToTotal
FROM CTE2 AS a
    OUTER APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE2 WHERE wono = a.wono AND Sequence < a.Sequence AND toWC = a.fromWC ORDER BY Sequence DESC ) AS b
    OUTER APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE2 WHERE wono = a.wono AND Sequence < a.Sequence AND fromWC = a.toWC ORDER BY Sequence DESC ) AS c
ORDER BY a.Sequence
```

**Note:** This solution would benefit greatly from an "ID" column, that mirrors transaction order OR at least you will need an index on `wono, transferDate, fromWC, toWC`

Comment: This is an interesting approach. It does produce the desired results and is much closer than I have ever made it. My biggest concern is the performance on a very large table. If someone else doesn't suggest a more efficient method, I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: @davids, I have added another solution. I think both approach would be resource heavy. As to which one would be faster you need to test yourself.

Comment: Looks like the first method is the most efficient, even with an ordered id column