# SQL Server, SQL Query Assistance Required

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1 : Employee

```
    EmpId  CreatedAt
    --------------------------
    100    2015-11-09 07:21:02
    200    2017-01-24 18:24:01
    300    2016-08-20 06:55:35
```

Table 2 : Account

```
    AccId   EmpID   Currency   CreatedAt
    -----------------------------------------------
    9000     100       USD     2017-04-20 19:40:55
    9001     200       USD     2017-04-20 19:40:55
    9002     100       EUR     2017-05-20 19:40:55
    9003     200       USD     2017-04-20 19:40:55
    9004     100       USD     2017-04-20 19:40:55
```

Table 3 : Transaction

```
  TrnsId   AccId Amount CreatedAt
  ------------------------------------------
  10       9000   3000  2017-04-25 19:40:55
  11       9001    500  2017-05-25 19:40:55
  12       9000   -200  2017-05-30 19:40:55
  13       9000   -500  2017-06-11 19:40:55
```

I need to calculate the ending balance for the account after each transaction entry. Assume that each account begins with a zero balance.

I have written this query:

```
SELECT 
    account.AccId, SUM(transaction.amount) AS [Ending Balance] 
FROM 
    account
JOIN 
    transaction ON transaction.AccId = account.AccId 
GROUP BY 
    account.AccId
```

but the results returned by the query are not correct.

Comment: How do you know the query is not correct?  Errors? (post the message), Incorrect results? (Post what you get and what you want)

Comment: With *"after each transaction entry"* do you mean *"running sum"*?

Comment: yes, i need running sum

Comment: Many methods to calculate a running total can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate running total / running balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance)

Comment: How can i do the running total query in my scenario?

Comment: Use the variant with `SUM(amt) OVER (ORDER BY TID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11313533/880990).