# SUM(y) OVER (ORDER BY x) SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sum, window-functions

I am executing the following query;

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_c 
(
     row_id NUMERIC(18) IDENTITY (1,1), 
     value NUMERIC(18)
)

INSERT #temp_c (value)
VALUES (1), (7), (10), (1), (12), (8), (6), (3)

SELECT 
    row_id,
    value,
    SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) total 
FROM 
    #temp_c

DROP TABLE #temp_c
```

And expect the following results

```
row_id                                  value                                   total
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1                                       1                                       1
2                                       7                                       8
3                                       10                                      18
4                                       1                                       19
5                                       12                                      31
6                                       8                                       39
7                                       6                                       45
8                                       3                                       48
```

When executing this code on SQL Server 2012 the above query functions as expected.

When executing this code on SQL Server 2008 R2 the query returns the following error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
```

[According to this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) I should be able to start using this query in 2008.

Please note the PARTITION BY syntax works on both versions, was the ORDER BY logic implemented at a later date?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. The partition by is fine in 2008, the order by is 2012 onward. Unfortunately, this sort of thing needed to be achieved with something like a self-join or a cross apply (with the same kind of logic as a self-join) in 2008.

Comment: Note the parts about aggregates in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189461(v=sql.105)) for reference. (Specifically: "<ORDER BY Clause> cannot be used with aggregate window functions.")

Comment: Thanks ZLK, hopefully I get something clean working here for both environments.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance