# Recursive CTE with partition by column

Tags: sql-server

Below are the table structure

```
drop table if exists #Transactions

create table #Transactions (TID int, amt int)

insert into #Transactions values(1, 100)
insert into #Transactions values(1, -50)
insert into #Transactions values(1, 100)
insert into #Transactions values(1, -100)
insert into #Transactions values(1, 200)


;WITH y AS 
(
  SELECT TID, amt, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TID)
    FROM #Transactions
), x AS
(
    SELECT TID, rn, amt, rt = amt
      FROM y
      WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.TID, y.rn, y.amt, x.rt + y.amt
      FROM x INNER JOIN y
      ON y.rn = x.rn + 1
)
SELECT TID, amt, RunningTotal = rt
  FROM x
  ORDER BY x.rn
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

This is similar to question [recursive cte with running balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance)

But I need to running balance for each TIds..suppose  if I insert to following transaction of TId=2

```
insert into #Transactions values(2, 100)
insert into #Transactions values(2, -50)
insert into #Transactions values(2, 100)
insert into #Transactions values(2, -100)
insert into #Transactions values(2, 200)
```

[image: Required output]

I need to achieve same only in recursive CTE method without lots of modification.. Please suggest a solution

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Comment: server 2017..but i need to achieve in cte only... i know window function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle `TID` in your `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and also `CTE` `JOIN`

```
;WITH y AS 
(
  SELECT TID, amt, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TID   -- <= added here
                                               ORDER BY TID)
    FROM #Transactions
), x AS
(
    SELECT TID, rn, amt, rt = amt
      FROM y
      WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.TID, y.rn, y.amt, x.rt + y.amt
      FROM x INNER JOIN y
      ON y.rn = x.rn + 1
     AND y.TID = x.TID                -- <= added here
)
SELECT TID, amt, RunningTotal = rt
  FROM x
  ORDER BY x.rn
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

Any compelling reason that you must use `CTE` instead of a simple `SUM()` with window function ?

Comment: Thanks for quick response..dont want to change existing prcedure

Comment: You should go for solution with window function. It is much more efficient than `CTE`. Check out the query by @Venkataraman R

Answer (score 2):

You dont need recursive CTE. You can simply for a PARTITION BY based approach.

```
SELECT tid
      , AMT
      , SUM(amt) OVER(PARTITION BY tid ORDER BY tid 
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                      ) AS RunningTotal
FROM #Transactions
```

**update**
Sorry. Just now, went through comments. 
If you have to use CTE, go with answer by @Squirrel. If you are fine with window functions, you can use the above approach.

Answer (score 2):

Add `Partition` with `TID`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f5b2977fe689e3df075204158be9625)**

```
;WITH y AS 
(
  SELECT TID, amt, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TID ORDER BY TID)
    FROM #Transactions
), x AS
(
    SELECT TID, rn, amt, rt = amt
      FROM y
      WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.TID, y.rn, y.amt,x.rt + y.amt 
      FROM x INNER JOIN y
      ON y.rn = x.rn + 1 AND x.TID = y.TID
)
SELECT TID, amt, RunningTotal = rt
  FROM x
  ORDER BY x.TID, x.rn
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```